# Importance of fabric grain in embroidery

Tags: embroidery, fabric-grain

If you wish to embroider, say, 3 meters of fabric to create a shawl, [do you still need to make sure the fabric is on grain](https://sew4home.com/tips-resources/sewing-tips-tricks/fabric-grain-what-it-and-how-fix-it-if-its)?
Or do you only check for fabric grain if you will cut for sewing projects?

Answer (score 1):

I know the weave of the cloth makes a very big difference.

I am a weaver and have seen professional looms in action. Grain, as I understand, is the Warp + Weft in threads per square mm, or inch.

The grain is a living part of a fabric.  I would take that into accord, but I've not done a lot of "fine embrodery". It is just logical.